# Manually Flush Kafka Connect Sinks?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have an existing Kafka production cluster. We'd like to build a new production Kafka cluster, move all clients over there, and terminate the existing cluster.

Can we manually flush all Kafka Connect sinks before we terminate the old cluster?

Comment: In general, you can pause or terminate them gracefully, which executes the internal lifecycle methods. This doesn't necessarily involve flushing

Comment: The S3 sink connector.